# Where are the Class objects created by classloader subsytem stored?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, stack-memory

I guess the newer versions of java have combined both method area and heap area as only one heap area. But this is regarding older versions.

But the jvm **loading** definition states as the **"process of finding a .class file and creating a Class object"**

These are my doubts:

1. When we run our .class file, is it first stored as **memory bits** as-is in method area? Is the complete .class file just converted to memory bits? Or just the metadata? What exactly is the pattern of memory allocation of this **"class data"** in method area?
2. Does a **Classloader** class use methods of **Class** class to obtain this metadata which is eventually stored in method area?
3. Are these Class objects same as objects we create using new?
   I already looked at the documentation but still cant figure out
   **during which step a Class object is created.** 
   Is the .class file information converted to metadata and saved as Class objects on method area?

I already looked at the documentation. I only need a simple explaination of what is "loaded"? Method area has Class objects that have this metadata ? Or just bit-by-bit info of the entire .class file ?

Edit: Also I know that by "writing/running a code" itself means this entire file is in bit format on RAM. I want to know if this special method area on RAM just has this copy or its completely different.

Comment: Newer versions still have the methods stored in a separate Metaspace

Comment: All data is bits/bytes in memory.

Comment: The Class is a proxy to the underlying data structure. I imagine the class loader uses the underlying structure directly, not the Class object.

Comment: A Class object exists on the heap like any other object expection you can't use `new` or any hack, to create this class except using a Classloader.

Comment: If Class object is in heap.what exactly is in method area.? Just the metadata? If the classloader is creating this metadata what does Class object contain and when is it created? whats the difference between the two?

Comment: The Class file is available for use by the programmer and only contains meta information the JVM designer though a programmer might reasonably need. e.g. it has no code.  The method area contains the method including their version optimised to native machine code.

Comment: @TimmyJoe did you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52663174/2711488)? It explains precisely when and how a `Class` object is created. It also names examples for the meta data stored in the Method Area.

Answer (score 1):

A `ClassLoader` is only responsible for locating and reading the class file and optionally, associate a `ProtectionDomain` with the code location, to support security measures.

It then passes the bytes to one of the [`defineClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String,byte%5B%5D,int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)) methods, every class loader inherits. These methods take the class file bytes, either as array or `ByteBuffer`, and do the entire magic, finally returning a `Class` object.

These `Class` objects are mostly like ordinary objects, but you never create them via `new`; only the JVM will create instances. Further, the JVM may associate additional information with these objects, not visible to the application programmer looking at the Java object.

What happens within `defineClass`, is implementation specific. But it is typical, not to store the class file bytes as-is. They likely contain information not needed for execution and required information may not be in the optimal format for the current platform (like byte order and preferred data alignment). Further, it makes sense to fold identical constants of different classes into one storage. Since the class data have to be checked for validity anyway, it makes sense to combine that processing step with converting the data into an internal format better suited for subsequent processing.

The complete runtime information regarding a class still are distributed over the heap (like the `Class` instance and its associated Reflection objects) and the Method Area (like code, linkage information, JVM internal structures, etc.). Note that these names are given by the specification, i.e. the Java Heap is [defined as the memory area containing all Java objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3) and the Method Area is [defined as the storage of the meta data](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4). Since this distinction is given *by definition*, regardless of whether it makes a difference to the particular implementation (after all, it’s just RAM), you won’t see an implementation dependent change in this classification.

Answer (score 0):

For a full explanation of how this works, you need to read chapter 5 of the Java Virtual Machine Specification.  The introduction states,

"*The Java Virtual Machine dynamically loads, links and initializes classes and interfaces. Loading is the process of finding the binary representation of a class or interface type with a particular name and creating a class or interface from that binary representation. Linking is the process of taking a class or interface and combining it into the run-time state of the Java Virtual Machine so that it can be executed. Initialization of a class or interface consists of executing the class or interface initialization method* "

To answer the specific questions:

1. The classfile is not loaded as-is into the method area, it is loaded as an implementation specific (meaning the JVMS doesn't mandate it) internal representation of the class.  Classes (other than array classes) are loaded by a class loader.  The class loader creates an instance of the Class object (i.e. the meta-data) for the given class. Allocation of space in the heap for this object is handled by the JVM.
2. No. The class loader is responsible for creating the Class object so does not use methods of that object.
3. Yes, Class objects are the same form as any other Java object.  The Class class inherits from Object and you can call methods such as equals, hachCode, etc. just as you would on other objects.

Comment: What is the internal representation of the class ? How is this different from metadata? And you mean Class objects are the metadata? And these Class class objects are stored on heap?